# how I can wait for load Ajax with idHTTP?

Tags: html, ajax, delphi, indy

I use IdHTTP.get for get the HTMl of a url, but in this url is a table that load with ajax and I must wait a few seconds to it loaded and after it get the HTML of page.

have can I wait for this?

Comment: Do you need to execute any ajax request? or a particular one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax uses client-side scripting to send background HTTP requests to the server and manipulate the HTML page that is already loaded in the browser.  `TIdHTTP` will download the raw HTML data, but you would then have to execute the Ajax scripting yourself and send those extra requests yourself if you want it to do something.  `TIdHTTP` (and Indy in general) cannot handle Ajax for you.

Comment: Yes I know that but my means that how can I wait for example 10 Seconds after completed loading and then read the HTML with TidHTTP.

Comment: You are missing the point. Once TIdHTTP has downloaded the initial HTML, that's it. A WebBrowser would then parse and display that HTML, executing the Ajax scripting, which would then use its own connections to send additional HTTP requests to the server and alter the WebBrowser's parsed contents accordingly, not the original HTML. The HTML that TIdHTTP downloads will not be the content that Ajax generates.

Comment: If you want to simulate what Ajax does, you would have to download the original HTML and store it off to the side, then parse it to determine what HTTP requests the Ajax scripting would produce, send those HTTP requests yourself, receive the responses from the server, and update the relevant portions of the saved HTML data accordingly.